# how to onclick for jsonobject/listview feed item?

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-rss-reader-20.html
I'm using eclipse and developing for android 2.0

here is the problem
*I cant figure out how to set an onclick listener or something similar to each article
*I'm trying to make it go to the website the article is from onclick

```
public class Utezone extends ListActivity {

private RssListAdapter adapter;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try {
        jobs = RssReader.getLatestRssFeed();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
    }





    adapter = new RssListAdapter(this,jobs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

```
public class RssListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

public RssListAdapter(Activity activity, List<JSONObject> imageAndTexts) {
    super(activity, 0, imageAndTexts);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate the views from XML
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_text_layout, null);
    JSONObject jsonImageText = getItem(position);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //The next section we update at runtime the text - as provided by the JSON from our REST call
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.job_text);

    try {
        Spanned text = (Spanned)jsonImageText.get("text");
        textView.setText(text);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        textView.setText("JSON Exception");
    }

    return rowView;

} 


}


public class RssReader {

private final static String BOLD_OPEN = "<B>";
private final static String BOLD_CLOSE = "</B>";
private final static String BREAK = "<BR>";
private final static String ITALIC_OPEN = "<I>";
private final static String ITALIC_CLOSE = "</I>";
private final static String SMALL_OPEN = "<SMALL>";
private final static String SMALL_CLOSE = "</SMALL>";

/**
 * This method defines a feed URL and then calles our SAX Handler to read the article list
 * from the stream
 * 
 * @return List<JSONObject> - suitable for the List View activity
 */
public static List<JSONObject> getLatestRssFeed(){
    String feed = "thefeedurl";

    RSSHandler rh = new RSSHandler();
    List<Article> articles =  rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
    Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Number of articles " + articles.size());
    return fillData(articles);
}


/**
 * This method takes a list of Article objects and converts them in to the 
 * correct JSON format so the info can be processed by our list view
 * 
 * @param articles - list<Article>
 * @return List<JSONObject> - suitable for the List View activity
 */
private static List<JSONObject> fillData(List<Article> articles) {

    List<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Article article : articles) {
        JSONObject current = new JSONObject();
        try {
            buildJsonObject(article, current);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error creating JSON Object from RSS feed");
        }
        items.add(current);
    }

    return items;
}


/**
 * This method takes a single Article Object and converts it in to a single JSON object
 * including some additional HTML formating so they can be displayed nicely
 * 
 * @param article
 * @param current
 * @throws JSONException
 */
private static void buildJsonObject(Article article, JSONObject current) throws JSONException {
    String title = article.getTitle();
    String description = article.getDescription();
    String date = article.getPubDate();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(BOLD_OPEN).append(title).append(BOLD_CLOSE);
    sb.append(BREAK);
    sb.append(description);
    sb.append(BREAK);
    sb.append(SMALL_OPEN).append(ITALIC_OPEN).append(date).append(ITALIC_CLOSE).append(SMALL_CLOSE);

    current.put("text", Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the activity extends ListActivity you can simply do:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A onclicklistener is bound to a listview. call getListView() and set it to a ListView ivar. On that ivar implement an OnItemClickListener by calling the method setOnItemClickListener();

```
ListView lw = getListView();
lw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener({
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {}

}));
```